# Python: fast dictionary of big int keys

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, int, biginteger

I have got a list of >10.000 int items. The values of the items can be very high, up to 10^27. Now I want to create all pairs of the items and calculate their sum. Then I want to look for different pairs with the same sum.

For example:

```
l[0] = 4
l[1] = 3
l[2] = 6
l[3] = 1
...

pairs[10] = [(0,2)] # 10 is the sum of the values of l[0] and l[2]
pairs[7] = [(0,1), (2,3)] # 7 is the sum of the values of l[0] and l[1] or l[2] and l[3]
pairs[5] = [(0,3)]
pairs[9] = [(1,2)]
...
```

The contents of `pairs[7]` is what I am looking for. It gives me two pairs with the same value sum.

I have implemented it as follows - and I wonder if it can be done faster. Currently, for 10.000 items it takes >6 hours on a fast machine. (As I said, the values of `l` and so the keys of `pairs` are ints up to 10^27.)

```
l = [4,3,6,1]
pairs = {}
for i in range( len( l  )  ):
    for j in range(i+1, len( l ) ):
        s = l[i] + l[j]
        if not s in pairs:
            pairs[s] = []
        pairs[s].append((i,j))

# pairs = {9: [(1, 2)], 10: [(0, 2)], 4: [(1, 3)], 5: [(0, 3)], 7: [(0, 1), (2, 3)]}
```

---

**Edit:** I want to add some background, as asked by Simon Stelling.

The goal is to find Formal Analogies like

```
lays : laid :: says : said
```

within a list of words like

```
[ lays, lay, laid, says, said, foo, bar ... ]
```

I already have a function `analogy(a,b,c,d)` giving `True` if `a : b :: c : d`. However, I would need to check all possible quadruples created from the list, which would be a complexity of around O((n^4)/2).

As a pre-filter, I want to use the char-count property. It says that every char has the same count in (a,d) and in (b,c). For instance, in "layssaid" we have got 2 a's, and so we do in "laidsays"

So the idea until now was

- for every word to create a "char count vector" and represent it as an integer (the items in the list `l`)
- create all pairings in `pairs` and see if there are "pair clusters", i.e. more than one pair for a particular char count vector sum.

And it works, it's just slow. The complexity is down to around O((n^2)/2) but this is still a lot, and especially the dictionary lookup and insert is done that often.

Comment: The problem is not the size of the ints, it's the fact that you have a doubly nested loop over all items which is in `O(n^2)`

Comment: did you really wait ofr 6 hours until it finished? however i suggest to take a look at PEP8 :)

Comment: ...also range returns a complete list with all items expanded, use xrange instead

Comment: Yep, another task from P ? NP  class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have came up with my own solution, just taking half of the calculation time on average.

The basic idea: Instead of reading and writing into the growing dictionary n^2 times, I first collect all the sums in a list. Then I sort the list. Within the sorted list, I then look for same neighbouring items.

This is the code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def getPairClusters( l ):

    # first, we just store all possible pairs sequentially
    # clustering will happen later
    pairs = []

    for i in xrange( len( l)  ):
        for j in xrange(i+1, len( l ) ):
            pair = l[i] + l[j]
            pairs.append( ( pair, i, j ) )
    pairs.sort(key=itemgetter(0))

    # pairs = [ (4, 1, 3), (5, 0, 3), (7, 0, 1), (7, 2, 3), (9, 1, 2), (10, 0, 2)]
    # a list item of pairs now contains a tuple (like (4, 1, 3)) with
    # * the sum of two l items: 4
    # * the index of the two l items: 1, 3

    # now clustering starts
    # we want to find neighbouring items as
    # (7, 0, 1), (7, 2, 3)
    # (since 7=7)

    pairClusters = []

    # flag if we are within a cluster
    # while iterating over pairs list
    withinCluster = False

            # iterate over pair list
    for i in xrange(len(pairs)-1):
        if not withinCluster:
            if pairs[i][0] == pairs[i+1][0]:
                # if not within a cluster
                # and found 2 neighbouring same numbers:
                # init new cluster
                pairCluster = [ ( pairs[i][1], pairs[i][2] ) ]
                withinCluster = True
        else:
            # if still within cluster
            if pairs[i][0] == pairs[i+1][0]:
                pairCluster.append( ( pairs[i][1], pairs[i][2] ) )
            # else cluster has ended
            # (next neighbouring item has different number)
            else:
                pairCluster.append( ( pairs[i][1], pairs[i][2] ) )
                pairClusters.append(pairCluster)
                withinCluster = False

    return pairClusters

l = [4,3,6,1]

print getPairClusters(l)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are the trivial optimizations like caching constant values in a local variable and using `xrange` instead of `range`:

```
pairs = {}
len_l = len(l)
for i in xrange(len_l):
    for j in xrange(i+1, len_l):
        s = l[i] + l[j]
        res = pairs.setdefault(s, [])
        res.append((i,j))
```

However, it is probably far more wise to not pre-calculate the list and instead optimize the method on a concept level. What is the intrinsic goal you want to achieve? Do you really just want to calculate what you do? Or are you going to use that result for something else? What is that something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added some background.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint. Have a look on [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

This is not exactly what you are looking for (because it stores pair of values, not of  indexes), but it can be a starting code:

```
from itertools import combinations
for (a, b) in combinations(l, 2):
    pairs.setdefault(a + b, []).append((a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

The above comment from SimonStelling is correct; generating all possible pairs is just fundamentally slow, and there's nothing you can do about it aside from altering your algorithm. The correct function to use from `itertools` is `product`; and you can get some minor improvements from not creating extra variables or doing unnecessary list indexes, but underneath the hood these are still all O(n^2). Here's how I would do it:

```
from itertools import product
l = [4,3,6,1]
pairs = {}
for (m,n) in product(l,repeat=2):
    pairs.setdefault(m+n, []).append((m,n))
```

Comment: The correct itertools function is `combinations()` as Don suggested. `product()` gives too much, as for instance the pair (4,1) _and_ (1,4).